# Getting this "Attribute error" over and over in python

Tags: python, class, attributes

Can anyone explain why this keeps happening to me?

```
class TourAgency:

    def __init__(self):            
        self._tours = {}
        self._scheduledtours = {}
        self._customers = {}
        self._booking = {}

    def addTour(self,code,tour):            
        self._tours[code] = tour

    def addscheduledtours(self,code,scheduledtour):            
        self._scheduledtours[code] = scheduledtour

    def addCustomer(self,code,customer):             
        self._customers[code] = customer

    def addBooking(self,bookingId,booking):            
        self._booking[bookingId] = booking

    def searchscheduledtours(self,code):           
        if code in self.scheduledtours.keys():             
            return self._scheduledtours[code]            
        else:
            return None


mytour = TourAgency()    
t1 = Tour("KO111","Discover Korea",8,7,1449.36)     
print(t1)    
ta = mytour.addTour('KO111',t1)    
print(TourAgency.tours)
```

I get an error saying:

> print(TourAgency.tours)
>
> AttributeError: type object 'TourAgency' has no attribute 'tours'

Comment: there is no attribute `tours` to the above class. try `print(TourAgency._tours)`.

Answer (score 0):

Your class hasn't got the **tours** attribute, it has only got the *_tours* attribute. Maybe you want to use it instead.

Remember that, in Python, if an attribute name starts with an underscore, it means that the attribute should be **private** and not intended to be used by the *user*.

I hope this could help you! Cheers!